# Add column with number of observations to esttab summary statistics table

Tags: stata

I would like to make a summary statistics table using `esttab` from the `estout` package on SSC. I can make the table just fine, but I would like to add a column that counts the number of non-missing observations for each variable. That is, some variables may not be complete and I would like this to be clear to the reader.

In the example below I removed the first five observations for `price`, so I would like a 69 in that row. But my code doesn't include row-specific observation counts, only the total number of observations in the footer.

```
sysuse auto, clear
estpost summarize, detail
replace price = . in 1/5
local screen ///
    cells("N mean sd min p50 max") ///
    nonumber label 
esttab, `screen'
```

This yields an empty `N` column, which I would prefer to have at 69 , followed by all 74s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this it:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- exmple data -----

sysuse auto, clear
keep price mpg rep78 headroom

replace price = . in 1/5

*----- what you want -----

estpost summarize, detail

local screen cells("count mean sd") nonumber label noobs

esttab, `screen'
```

?

It just uses `count`. `esttab` is a wrapper for `estout`, and the `help` for the latter documents that it will take "results from e(myel)", which you have from `estpost summarize, detail`.

An alternative is:

```
tabstat _all, statistics(count mean sd) columns(statistics)
```

Yet another one, only that it allows variable labels to be displayed:

```
fsum _all, stat(n mean sd) uselabel
```

`fsum` is from SSC.

Comment: TL;DR: Use `count` instead of `N`. :) Odd, because everywhere else `esttab` uses the macros name from `summarize`'s `return list`. Thanks!